# Error in kernel 2.6.32 compilation and stable kernel 2.6.32 source needed for customization

Tags: linux, ubuntu-10.04, arch-linux, linux-kernel, kernel-panic

I am using Ubuntu 10.04 LTS with kernel 2.6.32-21-generic , and Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS with kernel 2.6.32-38-generic.

While I am trying to compile the source for both kernel version - 2.6.32-21-generic and 2.6.32-38-generic, I got following error.

> **" error: .size expression for do_hypervisor_callback does not evaluate to a constant "**
>
> > > make[2]: *** [arch/x86/kernel/entry_64.o]
> > >
> > > [arch/x86/kernel] Error 2
> > >
> > > make: *** [arch/x86] Error 2Error 1 make[1]: ***

While searching in internet, several places I have seen the questions, but no answer except mentioning it is a bug . I am wondering Ubuntu 10.04 LTS is a stable version, but kernel has bug that too so many users pointed out about the bug.

Can anyone help me to figure out stable kernel version 2.6 source code so that I can download/compile the source code for 2.6 kernel and do my OS assignment.

BTW, I can't use kernel 3.0 , although Ubuntu 12.04 LTS has kernel 3.11.0-15 and I am successfully able to compile that kernel, but I need to compile kernel 2.6 for my work.

So should I go with Arch-Linux(Fedora) or stick to Ubuntu ?

So it will be great if any clue how to successfully compile kernel 2.6 or find a stable kernel 2.6 . Thanks in advance :)

Comment: The linux kernel is in the same place it always is kernel.org

Comment: @Ramhound how to solve the compilation error ? Should I use patch ? Can I use other kernel version ( like 2.6.32.61 available in kernel.org) in Ubuntu 10.04?

Comment: The current error your getting is a compiler error.  It also seems incomplete.  Are you making modifications because its odd source code that in theory was compiled and released months ago has an error in it.

Comment: @Ramhound I have modified in one source file and then trying to execute "make" command. At that time I was getting that error. Yah it's a compiler error.

Comment: @Ramhound I have downloaded kernel 2.6.32.61 source from the kernel.org and now while executing make command the error is not there. It is still going on, looks like it is building the kernel. Don't know how much time it will take , but I am happy that it is working now. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

This looks more like an issue with XEN in your .config file. This happened to be before, and got resolved by disabling this part.
Search for

```
CONFIG_XEN=y
```

and change it to

```
CONFIG_XEN=n
```

Happy compiling.